# iptables rules revert on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, firewall, iptables

I'm using iptables on Ubuntu 10.04 and whenever I set iptables rules they will revert after a while. I set them with iptables -I INPUT or iptables -D INPUT and they work immediately and I see them in iptables -L INPUT but after a while the rules revert.

I even exported the rules

```
iptables-save > /etc/firewall.conf
```

I even created a script /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/firewall.conf
```

and I even checked firewall.conf and it has the rules I want in it.

So why would iptables be reverting?

UPDATE:

I found this in /etc/cron.daily/apf

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/apf/apf -f >> /dev/null 2>&1
/etc/apf/apf -s >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Would this be flushing the iptables rules?

Answer (score 1):

The wiki page references feisty etc. so *may* be out of date but I would guess its still relevant:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Configuration%20on%20startup suggests that NetworkManager may be the culprit...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Configuration%20on%20Startup%20for%20NetworkManager then suggests how to get NetworkManager to play nice.

Comment: There is no /etc/NetworkManager on my system and man -k Network Manager doesn't show anything which looks like it... I think Network Manager isn't installed on my system

Comment: Are you sure? The capitalisation of the 'N' & 'M' is important.

Comment: yes. very sure
ls /etc/N*
ls: cannot access /etc/N*: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with apf, but it's easy enough to check if that's the culprit.  Remove it from cron.

I'd also do something like `grep -ri --color iptables /etc` and also check `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog` for anything that could be doing this.

Comment: Yeah I had already grepped for iptables under etc but there is nothing (other then my above-mentioned script). Good idea with grepping the logs too but there was nothing there either. I've confirmed that the apf script flushes the iptables rules so I'Ve removed it. Now I just have to wait until the daily cron goes... This was a tricky one since the script flushing the iptables rules doesn't have the word "iptables" in it